# Why can't I deserialize a KnownType'd anyType?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to use DataContractSerializer outside of WCF to serialize an object. The object in this case inherits from an old generic wrapper around CollectionBase e.g.

```
[KnownType(typeof(Foo)]
[CollectionDataContract]
class FooCollection : MyCollectionBase<Foo>

[KnownType(typeof(FooCollection)]
[KnownType(typeof(Foo)]
[CollectionDataContract]
class MyCollectionBase<T> : CollectionBase

[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    string Name;
    [DataMember]
    string Value;
}
```

When this is serialized, I'm getting the following structure:

```
<FooCollection xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/ ...>
  <anyType>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <Value>...</Value>
  </anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

On deserializing I get the error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Element anyType from namespace http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAssembly cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.
>
> ----> System.Xml.XmlException : End element 'anyType' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAssembly' expected. Found element 'Name' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAssembly'. Line 1, position xxx.

Googling this error shows a number of people who changed up their inheritance hierarchy to get the serialization working, or simply list problems with the approach. I haven't been able to find any examples of *using XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.*

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to convince the DataContractSerializer that the type stored in the underlying ArrayList is of type Foo?
2. How do I implement the XmlNode[] workaround?
3. Is the only solution to use a generic collection that isn't backed by a non-generic one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue, not shown in my original question: MyCollectionBase implemented ISerializable.

The DataContractSerializer will use an ISerializable implementation before it uses any attributes. It also can't infer a contract from ISerializable, therefore there's no workaround for the `anyType` deserialization.

This is why the KnownTypeAttribute wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code above I used the following code to serialize and deserialize:

```
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FooCollection));
        IList collection = new FooCollection();
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Name = "TestName";
        foo.Value = "Test value";
        collection.Add(foo);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(writer);

        serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, collection);
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        var serialized = sb.ToString();

        var reader = new StringReader(serialized);
        var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader);
        var deserialized = serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);

        return;
```

without any problems using .Net 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010.
If you want to change the name of the element so that it is not 'anyType' you can change the CollectionDataContract attribute on the FooCollection class to read:

```
    [CollectionDataContract(ItemName="Foo")]
```